# Pyqt5: passing a name form login to Main-Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm connecting a login window to a main window, but I need to pass the login username to next window, noting that they are in different classes.

my code below:

```py
FROM_CLASS, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "Main_rfi-design2.ui"))
FROM_CLASS2, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "login_rfi.ui"))

class Login(QMainWindow, FROM_CLASS2):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_login.clicked.connect(self.handel_login)
        self.window2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Login, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_login.clicked.connect(self.handel_login)
        self.window2 = None

    def handel_login(self):
        self.db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="db_co")
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()

        self.user_name = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.password = self.lineEdit_16.text()

        sql = '''SELECT user_name FROM users'''
        self.cur.execute(sql)
        users = self.cur.fetchall()
        users = [i for sub in users for i in sub]
        sql2 = '''SELECT pass FROM users'''
        self.cur.execute(sql2)
        pass1 = self.cur.fetchall()
        pass1 = [i for sub in pass1 for i in sub]

        if self.user_name in users:
            user_index = users.index(self.user_name)
            if self.password == pass1[user_index]:
                self.window2 = Main()
                # self.window2 = Main(Login.return_username())
                self.close()
                self.window2.show()
            else:
                self.label.setText('Please check User Name or Password...')
        else:
            self.label.setText('User name dose not exist...')
            print('Current user is: ' + self.user_name)

class Main(QMainWindow, FROM_CLASS):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # To start applaying functions:
        self.initUI()
        self.handel_button()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main window, create a setter function that allows you to set the name String. Call/invoke that from the login window as appropriate (assuming the main window creates the login window and provides the child with a reference to itself). This will also work if you want to pass the result of login to a new window, provided that the main window creates the relevant subsequent/child windows.

The following code (which I haven't verified as functional and may need alteration) should get you started:

```py
# in Main class:

def setName(n):
  if n is not None and len(n) > 0:  # Check might not be required if you're OK with empty names
    self.name = n

# in function that creates login Window, create the login window with a reference
  # window creation might already take a "parent" param, in which case you're all set.
  createLoginWindow(requiredParams, main=self) 

# in LoginWindow init/constructor:
  self.mainWindow = main

# When name changes:
self.mainWindow.setName(name)
```